# angular.js:13424 TypeError: $interval.cancel is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I ecounter a problem.

> ```
> angular.js:13424 TypeError: $interval.cancel is not a function
>     at ChildScope.$scope.updatetime
> ```

---

My code:

```
$scope.updatetime = function () {
    var current_time = new Date();
    $scope.nowitem = {};
    var hour = current_time.getHours();
        .
        .
        .
    $interval.cancel($scope.checkupdate);
        .
        .
}


$scope.checkupdate = $interval($scope.updatetime, 1000);
$scope.updatetime();
```

How to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create a demo replicating this issue?

Comment: The question needs http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It is obvious that code that causes the problem wasn't posted.

Comment: I don't know how to make a mcve of my real code in this site. I think it is a little bit complex so hard to make a mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've passed **$interval** in controller. Like this:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
```

Comment: @Aaron You haven't, otherwise you wouldn't have this error.